# Microsoft Graph Client Update user onPremisesExtensionAttributes.extensionAttributeXX

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How do you update the onPremisesExtensionAttributes.extensionAttributes8 on a user using Graph client for example?

Please note that I'm using the beta (Microsoft.Graph.Beta version 0.4.0-preview) for the graph SDK. I don't want to use v1.0 as of now, due to some limitations with v1.0

I've tried this but this does not compile

```
            var graphServiceClient = CreateGraphServiceClient();
        //graphServiceClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";


        var user = graphServiceClient.Users["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"].Request()
                                                      .Select("id,accountEnabled,mail,OnPremisesExtensionAttributes,userType,displayName,source,externalUserState")
                                                      .GetAsync()
                                                      .Result;            

        User updatedUser = new User()
        {
            OnPremisesExtensionAttributes.ExtensionAttribute8 = "1"
        };

        await graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(updatedUser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting `updatedUser`, you initialize a new instance of `User`, but you forgot to also initialize a new instance of `OnPremisesExtensionAttributes` before trying to set a value for `ExtensionAttribute8`.

The following would be a correct way of initializing `updatedUser` all in one go:

```
User updatedUser = new User()
{
    OnPremisesExtensionAttributes = new OnPremisesExtensionAttributes()
    {
        ExtensionAttribute8 = "1"
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could do the same thing like this:

```
User updatedUser = new User();
updatedUser.OnPremisesExtensionAttributes = new OnPremisesExtensionAttributes();
updatedUser.OnPremisesExtensionAttributes.ExtensionAttribute8 = "1";
```